# Where Are SalesForce Notes Stored?

Tags: salesforce

Does anybody know which table stores the 'Notes' in Salesforce.

I believe they are the new type of note.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query `Note` sobject.

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Title, Body FROM Note
```

Have a look at more or [Note](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_note.htm).